# Division and rounding of BigInteger

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ienumerable, biginteger

I'm trying to create a collection which has decimals with precision rounded to 2 decimal places. However the collection have some huge numbers and I have to use the BigInteger as the solution.

The specifics:
- Got a collection which has BigIntegers
- Got another collection of BigIntegers
- Got a third collection of Big integers
- I have to create a collection which has average value of the above 3 collections, with values rounded to 2 decimal places.
i.e if collection1 has {2,3,4} and collection2 has {4,5,5} and collection3 has {5,3,2} I should create a 4th collection which has {3.67,3.67,,3.67}

For this I'm using this code:

```
     BigInteger divisor = new BigInteger(3.0d);
     var averages = collection1.Zip(collection2, BigInteger.Add)
                    .Zip(collection3, 
                    (xy, z) => BigInteger.Divide(BigInteger.Add(xy,z), divisor));
```

However the decimals are not appearing. I'm not sure as to whether biginteger can hold only integer values and not decimal values.

Can you please suggest a solution for this?

Note: It has to be LINQ based as the collections are pretty huge with some big values(and hence biginteger).

Comment: Hint: **Integer**. [ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin)

Comment: Even BigInteger stays Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're not getting any decimal values because `BigInteger` only represents *integers*.

Is `decimal` big enough to hold the number you're interested in?

If not, you might want to consider multiplying everthing by 100, and fixing the formatting side such that "1500" is displayed as "15.00" etc. You'd still need to do a bit of work to end up with ".67" instead of ".66" for a two-thirds result, as that would be the natural result of the division when it's truncated instead of rounded.

Comment: Decimal is not good enough as it has to hold  the 1000th number in the fibonacci series which is 434665576869374564356885276750 406258025646605173717804024817 290895365554179490518904038798 400792551692959225930803226347 752096896232398733224711616429 964409065331879382989696499285 16003704476137795166849228875.

Comment: @Mike: Out of interest, *why* do you need to take the average of three Fibonacci numbers? That sounds like a very odd requirement.

Comment: Yes, it's and is only for academic purposes.

Comment: @Mike: In that case, does it matter if you show "the average multiplied by 100" or even just the sum instead of the average?

Comment: Yes, the average multipled by 100 and fixing it on the formatting side will help. I'm currently checking that. Please can you tell me what format specifier should I be using for it?

Comment: @Mike: You'd have to do something custom, I suspect - after all, BigInteger is aimed at *integers*. You'd probably have to format it, then insert the "." before the last two digits.

Comment: If you want to format it with commas, multiply the numbers by 1,000 then format the result with commas (e.g. `String.Format(i,"{0:N}")`, then change the last comma to a period.  If you want you can also chop off the last digit to get 2 "decimal" places.

Answer (score 0):

The residue after division by three is going to either be .00, .33, or .67.  You should be able to determine which of those three values is appropriate.  I'm not sure how you will want to have your collection store things, however, given that the numerical types that support fractions won't be able to hold your result, unless you want to define a "big integer plus small fraction" type or store your numbers as strings.